# Excel VBA export to csv in batches of 5

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to export some excel data to .csv in batches of 5 data rows plus 1 header.

My first file has 4 data rows which should be 5 plus the header as shown below

```
latitude,longitude,altitude(m),heading(deg),curvesize(m),rotationdir,gimbalmode,gimbalpitchangle,actiontype1,actionparam1
1,-0.5643113,100,0,0,0,2,-90,1,0
2,-0.56499336,100,180,0,0,2,-90,1,0
3,-0.56499336,100,180,0,0,2,-90,1,0
4,-0.56499336,100,180,0,0,2,-90,1,0
```

Whereas the remaining files have 5 data rows (which is correct)

```
latitude,longitude,altitude(m),heading(deg),curvesize(m),rotationdir,gimbalmode,gimbalpitchangle,actiontype1,actionparam1
5,-0.56499336,100,180,0,0,2,-90,1,0
6,-0.56815177,100,0,0,0,2,-90,1,0
7,-0.56815177,100,0,0,0,2,-90,1,0
8,-0.56815177,100,0,0,0,2,-90,1,0
9,-0.56815177,100,0,0,0,2,-90,1,0
```

Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

```
Sub Export()
    Dim FileNum As Integer
    Dim Last_Row As Long
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim TotalFileNum As Integer
    Dim myStr As String
    Dim MYFILE As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Long

    MYFILE = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set My_Range = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:J" & Last_Row)

    Open MYFILE & "Litch 0.csv" For Output As #FileNum

    'Put out the headers
    myStr = Cells(1, 1).Value
    For i = 2 To 10
        myStr = myStr & "," & Cells(1, i).Value
    Next i
    Print #FileNum, myStr



    For j = 2 To Last_Row
        If (j - 1) Mod 5 = 0 Then
            Close #FileNum
            Open MYFILE & "Litch " & ((j - 1) \ 5) & ".csv" For Output As #FileNum

            'Put out the headers
            myStr = Cells(1, 1).Value
            For i = 2 To 10
                myStr = myStr & "," & Cells(1, i).Value
            Next i
            Print #FileNum, myStr
            TotalFileNum = (j \ 5) + 1
        End If

        'Put out the values
        myStr = Cells(j, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To 10
            myStr = myStr & "," & Cells(j, i).Value
        Next i
        Print #FileNum, myStr

    Next j
    Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's better to do everything in the loop

```
Option Explicit

Sub Export()
Dim FileNum As Integer
Dim Last_Row As Long
Dim My_Range As Range
Dim TotalFileNum As Integer
Dim myStr As String
Dim MYFILE As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long

    MYFILE = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"    

    Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set My_Range = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:J" & Last_Row)

    For j = 1 To Last_Row

        If j = Last_Row Then
            Close #FileNum
            Exit For
        End If

        If (j - 1) Mod 5 = 0 Then

            FileNum = FreeFile
            Open MYFILE & "Litch " & ((j - 1) \ 5) & ".csv" For Output As #FileNum

            'Put out the headers
            myStr = Cells(1, 1).Value
            For i = 2 To 10
                myStr = myStr & "," & Cells(1, i).Value
            Next i
            Print #FileNum, myStr
            TotalFileNum = (j \ 5) + 1

        End If

        'Put out the values
        myStr = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value
        For i = 2 To 10
            myStr = myStr & "," & Cells(j + 1, i).Value
        Next i

        Print #FileNum, myStr

        If j Mod 5 = 0 Then
            Close #FileNum
        End If

    Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a bad filename or number on the print line at the bottom

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry, you have to close the file after five lines have been written. Are you able to fix that?

Comment: I did try but I either put it in the wrong place or the issue is somewhere else

Comment: Thanks but the first file has the header repeated twice and still only 4 data rows

Comment: Changed the code, that means I also adjusted the offset of j in cells. Please mention next time that the code is not yours.